# how to change color of the part of header title in tableView in swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, textcolor

I have read similar questions But I didn't got the answer :
I have Table View With Headers and the first one has title and a number I want to change the color of that number in the header in table view 
here is my codes :

```
var headerList = ["Account" , "Help" , "" ]

override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
self.headerList[0] = "Account \(userAccountMoney)"

 }
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let returnedView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    returnedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 229/255, green: 233/255, blue: 236/255, alpha: 1.0)

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: -20, y: 7, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    label.text = self.headerList[section]
    label.textAlignment = .right
    label.textColor = .lightGray
 }
```

as you See in my codes the header Titles Are Gray But I want in the first header Title the Account word Still be Gray But the userAccountMoney be the Green the problem is that because userAccountMoney is another variable I couldn't use similar questions

Comment: Create an `NSAttributedString` and use the property `attributedText`

Comment: I have read the similar questions But the problem is that I want to change textColor But not all of the words in the first header title

Comment: `NSAttributedString` is the solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the color of a part of a string you need to use `NS(Mutable)AttributedString` and add the color attribute only to the specific range:

```
if section == 0 {
    let sectionTitle = self.headerList[0]
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: sectionTitle)
    if sectionTitle.characters.count > 8 {
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: 8, length: sectionTitle.characters.count - 8))
    }
    label.attributedText = attributedString
} else {
    label.text = self.headerList[section]
}
```

The index 8 is the hard-coded index after `"Account "`

---

However in your case I'd recommend to create `headerList` as constant

```
let headerList = ["" , "Help" , "" ]
```

then delete the code in `viewDidLoad` and use this code to create the account amount dynamically

```
if section == 0 {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Account ")
    attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\(userAccountMoney)", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red]))
    label.attributedText = attributedString
} else {
    label.text = self.headerList[section]
}
```

Comment: I Receive Error When Used This Code

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Then you are reloading the table view before changing the section header in `viewDidLoad()`. I updated the answer with a check.

Comment: Worked Well Thanks A lot

Answer (score 1):

Using NSAttributedString you can create two multiple colour text, even you can change the font. Here is the snippet:

```
let titleAtt = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue])
let numberAtt = NSAttributedString(string: "123", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])

let combinationAtt = NSMutableAttributedString() 
combinationAtt.append(titleAtt)
combinationAtt.append(numberAtt)
label.attributedText = combinationAtt
```

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand your problem completely but I think you want to set different color for your first tableview header.
You want do this by using If-else statement on `section` variable.
Like this

```
func setAttributedString(text string : String, subStringRange range : NSRange, subStringFont font1 : UIFont, mainStringFont font2 : UIFont, subStringColor color1 : UIColor = UIColor.gray, mainStringColor color2 : UIColor = UIColor.green) -> NSAttributedString {

            let mainStringAttribute = [ NSFontAttributeName: font2, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color2] as [String : Any]
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: mainStringAttribute)

            let subStringAttribute = [ NSFontAttributeName: font1, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color1] as [String : Any]
            attributedString.addAttributes(subStringAttribute, range: range)

            return attributedString
        }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

     if (section == 0) // this is first header
     { 

    let returnedView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    returnedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 229/255, green: 233/255, blue: 236/255, alpha: 1.0)

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: -20, y: 7, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    label.text = self.headerList[section]
    label.textAlignment = .right
        let font1 = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        let font2 = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)

        label.attributedText = setAttributedString(text: "", subStringRange: NSRange(location: 0, length: 1), subStringFont: font1, mainStringFont: font2)


  } 
   else /// remaining headers
   {

 let returnedView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    returnedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 229/255, green: 233/255, blue: 236/255, alpha: 1.0)

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: -20, y: 7, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    label.text = self.headerList[section]
    label.textAlignment = .right
    label.textColor = .lightGray
}
 }
```

Comment: I don't Want to change all of the textColor in section 0 
I just Want to change text Color one of the words in section 0

Comment: now check please. I have added new method in which your pass your string and a range of which text you want to change color. Tell me if you still face any problem

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by writing like below code:

I have created one common function to reuse it in every controller.

```
//MARK:- Set title with two different color
func setTitle(title : String, loc : Int, len : Int) -> NSMutableAttributedString
{
    let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: title,
        attributes: [:])

    myMutableString.addAttribute(
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
        value: UIColor(red: 29/255, green: 140/255, blue: 242/255, alpha: 1.0),
        range: NSRange(
            location:loc,
            length:len))

    return myMutableString
}
```

I am using this fuction like,

For same controller you can write it,

```
self.lblTitle.attributedText = self.setTitle(title: "My Profile", loc: 3, len: 7)
```

You can also use this to change color of specific characters. You need to specify lenght of string and starting location of characters.